# ImageResizer showing no errors, but not working on IIS6

Tags: imageresizer

I just installed imageresizer on IIS6 .NET2 and downloaded the JCropExample2 sample project.  I get no errors, but a: the images do not resize on page load and b: the cropping does not work.  No errors are shown.  I am new to .NET, so really not sure what I have missed??

ImageResizer Debug:

```
2 Issues detected:

(Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.


(Warning):  NoCache is only for development usage, and cannot scale to production use.
            Add DiskCache or CloudFront for production use


You are not using any paid bundles.

Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting

Configuration:

<resizer>
<pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />
<plugins />
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, scale, stretch, crop, cropxunits, cropyunits, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, ignoreicc, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, anchor, dpi, mode, zoom, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/6.0 on Microsoft Windows NT 5.2.3790 Service Pack 2 and CLR 2.0.50727.3634
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: x86
Executing assembly: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: False

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.50727.3634  Info: 2.0.50727.3634
System.Web                               Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.50727.3634  Info: 2.0.50727.3634
System                                   Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.50727.3634  Info: 2.0.50727.3634
System.Xml                               Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.50727.3082  Info: 2.0.50727.3082
System.Configuration                     Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.50727.3053  Info: 2.0.50727.3053
System.Data                              Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.50727.3053  Info: 2.0.50727.3053
System.Web.RegularExpressions            Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.50727.3053  Info: 2.0.50727.3053
Microsoft.JScript                        Assembly: 8.0.0.0         File: 8.0.50727.3053  Info: 8.0.50727.3053
System.Web.Mobile                        Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.50727.3053  Info: 2.0.50727.3053
System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.4506.3636   Info: 3.0.4506.3636
System.Web.Services                      Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.50727.3053  Info: 2.0.50727.3053
System.Drawing                           Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.50727.3639  Info: 2.0.50727.3639
System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.50727.3053  Info: 2.0.50727.3053
ImageResizer                             Assembly: 3.2.3.302       File: 3.2.3.302       Info: 3-2-beta-3  Commit: 245e873
System.ServiceModel.Web                  Assembly: 3.5.0.0         File: 3.5.594.1152    Info: 3.5.594.1152
System.WorkflowServices                  Assembly: 3.5.0.0         File: 3.5.594.1152    Info: 3.5.594.1152
System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.4506.3636   Info: 3.0.4506.3636
System.IdentityModel                     Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.4506.3636   Info: 3.0.4506.3636
SMDiagnostics                            Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.4506.3636   Info: 3.0.4506.3636
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine. You failed to read the step 3 of 3 [on the homepage](http://imageresizing.net)

```
<!-- Unless you (a) use Integrated mode, or (b) map all reqeusts to ASP.NET, 
     you'll need to add .ashx to your image URLs: image.jpg.ashx?width=200&height=20 -->
         <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />
```

As you're using IIS6, which does not have Integrated mode, you have to use the .jpg.ashx syntax.

http://resizer.puremobi.com/JCropExample2/fountain-small.jpg.ashx?width=400

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response.  You are absolutely correct with your answer, although I did not miss that step, just was not sure how it was implemented.  When I edit the page as follows:  Can you please advise what 'map all reqeusts to ASP.NET' means and is achieved, as this sounds like a better option perhaps...

Comment: My initial attempts at implementation failure were due to a typo -lol-

Comment: OK, I found the naswer thank, to map all requests to ASP.NET
http://imageresizing.net/docs/cleanurls